# Threads at onCreate() method execute before setting the view

Tags: java, android, mobile, oncreate

I'm creating my splash screen for app. While loading it executes 4 methods. First one checks if Internet permission is granted, second one sends request to API to check if it is Online, third one is getting Token from Firebase and the fourth one is checking if user is already logged-in. I'm doing it using 4 threads. Each method in case of error sets the flag as false. Then when all the threads end their work (I used .join()) The last method checks the state of flag and launch new activity or just display Error and try everything once again.

The problem I have is that I'm getting the view after all the threads finish their work. For example I have black screen, then message ("Error occured") and only after that I can see UI. But on Error the UI is refreshed, so one more time I have black screen, then result and UI for 1sec until another restart.

My question is, can I in some way stop these Threads until my UI is ready ?

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    checkProgress = findViewById(R.id.checkProgressText);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    tokenUtils = new TokenUtils();

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    animatedCircleLoadingView = findViewById(R.id.circle_loading_view);

    //starting the animation
    startLoading();

    Thread[] checkers = new Thread[4];
    checkers[0] = new Thread(this::checkInternetPermissions);
    checkers[1] = new Thread(this::checkConnection);
    checkers[2] = new Thread(this::getUserAuth);
    checkers[3] = new Thread(this::getUserToken);

    for (Thread t : checkers) {
        try {
            t.start();
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    changeActivity();
}
```

Check internet permission method:

```
  private void checkInternetPermissions() {
    checkProgress.setText(getString(R.string.check_internet_permissions_text));
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 1);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode != 1) {
        connectionFlag = false;
    }
}
```

Check connection method:

```
private void checkConnection() {
    checkProgress.setText(getString(R.string.checking_api_connection));
    RequestFuture<String> requestFuture = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, API_CHECK,
                    requestFuture,
                    requestFuture);
    requestQueue.add(request);

    String response = null;
    try {
        response = requestFuture.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        this.connectionFlag = false;
    }

    if (!Objects.equals(response, "ok"))
        this.connectionFlag = false;
}
```

Get user token method:

```
private void getUserToken() {
    checkProgress.setText(getString(R.string.getting_user_auth_token));
    String token = null;
    try {
        token = tokenUtils.getFirebaseToken();
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        this.connectionFlag = false;
    }
    if (Objects.isNull(token) || Objects.requireNonNull(token).isEmpty())
        this.connectionFlag = false;
}
```

And finally get user auth method:

```
private void getUserAuth() {
    checkProgress.setText(getString(R.string.checking_user_auth));
    authStateListener = firebaseAuth -> {
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (Objects.isNull(firebaseUser) || Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseUser.getEmail()).isEmpty()) {
            this.authFlag = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Last method which handle the states of flags:

```
private void changeActivity() {
    checkProgress.setText(getString(R.string.finalizing_text_progress));
    if (connectionFlag && authFlag) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MapActivity.class));
    } else if (!connectionFlag) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can try it with handler thread with some delay then it will work fine or you can start your thread on onResume() method at the time of onResume your view will have been created

Comment: I tried using new Handler().postDelayed() on last method with even 10seconds of delay to make 100% sure the rest of methods end, but it still didn't work

Comment: try to start your thread on onResume() method at that time view will have been created

Comment: oh I will try it and let you know

Comment: While doin' it onResume() my app doesnt even start, or start and instant close without any exception etc

Comment: I removed threads and just put all 4 methods in synchronized(this) block and the last method was delayed of 2second and in this case everything works as it should

Answer (score 0):

I think, your way wrong. Because, API request working on asynchronous. Your app should run like this;

1. Check Internet connection.
2. API Request.
3. Get token in API Request onSuccess method.
4. Get User Auth.

I think, you shouldn't use Thread.

Comment: API Request is poiting to my local server, but Token is being got from Google Firebase API (there are two different APIs)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand.